# What is the largest gravitationally bound structure in the universe?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, estimation, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I understand the galaxy superclusters are not bound due to dark energy.  I wonder what matter scale will remain gravitationally bound - galaxy clusters, galaxies, stars - if anything at all, as dark energy dominates the fate of the universe.

Comment: The galaxy super-clusters will eventually be absorbed into black holes

Answer (score 2):

The largest gravitationally bound structure *that we know of* seems to be the [Shapley Supercluster SCI124](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley_Supercluster) - further details in [this paper](https://www.eso.org/sci/publications/messenger/archive/no.107-mar02/messenger-no107-18-23.pdf).